# .NET 7.0 - как прервать поток?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net-7

У меня есть многопоточная программа, и при вызове метода `Abort()` или `Suspend()`, компилятор выбрасывает PlatformNotSupportedException. Есть ли другие ***короткие*** способы приостановить поток? C# 11, .NET 7.0

Comment: [2-я ссылка гугла](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete) по запросу `c# thread abort`. Советую научится искать информацию самостоятельно, ведь это основа основ любого программиста.

Comment: Зарегистрируйте нормальный аккаунт на StackOverflow. Здесь принято отвечать на вопросы в комментариях. А вы задаете вопрос и тут же забрасываете его. Зачем тогда задавать? Люди пишут ответы, время тратят, для чего? Я написал ответ, реакции ноль. Пришлось удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Это ожидаемое поведение, `Suspend()` вызывает `PlatformNotSupportedException` всегда для .NET Core и .NET 5+.

Вместо этого нужно использовать `AutoResetEvent`:

Когда нужно просигнализировать об остановке, вызывать

```
autoResetEvent.Set();
```

В потоке соответственно использовать:

```
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Еще об этом посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382173/what-are-alternative-ways-to-suspend-and-resume-a-thread)

Comment: `AutoResetEvent` - штука мощная и тяжелая, и не поддерживает асинхронное ожидание. Есть более легковесные примитивы синхронизации, например `ManualResetEventSlim` или `SemaphoreSlim`, последний поддерживает асинхронность.

Comment: @aepot SemaphoreSlim прекрасная вещь, это же пример просто